# How to concatenate values in multiple cells based on a condition?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup, textjoin

I have a need to search a row of cells, and for every cell that contains a specific value, return the value from the cell above.

For example, consider the following

```
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
|   |   A    |   B    |   C    |   D    |   E    |     F    |
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| 1 |   UK   |   DE   |   FR   |   HK   |   TW   |          |
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| 2 |   YES  |        |   YES  |   YES  |        |          |
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| 3 |        |   YES  |        |   YES  |   YES  |          |
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
| 4 |   YES  |        |        |   YES  |        |          |
+---+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+----------+
```

So I want to insert a formula into cells F2, F3 and F4 which will give the following results

```
F2 = UK,FR,HK
F3 = DE,HK,TW
F4 = UK,HK
```

Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I have found a simple, scalable solution that uses an array formula to concatenate multiple cells that satisfy a certain condition.

Applied to your example, paste into cell F2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF(B3:F3 = "YES", B$2:F$2, ""))
```

and hit **ctrl+shift+enter** to enter as an **array formula**, and copy over cells F3--F4.

The reason why this works is left as an exercise to the reader. It's fairly clear, but I prefer "magic".

I hope this helps anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: Note that TEXTJOIN is only available in Excel 2016 and Office 365.

Answer (score 3):

### Write your own UDF

### [Original solution.](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2723-excel-concatenate-based-on-criteria.html)

### Excerpt from the article

1. Open VBA Editor by clicking *Visual Basic* on *Developer* tab or using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> combination
2. Create new module by right clicking *Microsoft Excel Objects* in the top left corner and choosing *Insert->Module* from the context menu.
3. Insert the following code

UDF:

```
Function ConcatenateIf(CriteriaRange As Range, _
                       Condition As Variant, _
                       ConcatenateRange As Range, _
                       Optional Separator As String = ",") As Variant
'Update 20150414
Dim xResult As String
On Error Resume Next
If CriteriaRange.Count <> ConcatenateRange.Count Then
    ConcatenateIf = CVErr(xlErrRef)
    Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To CriteriaRange.Count
    If CriteriaRange.Cells(i).Value = Condition Then
        xResult = xResult & Separator & ConcatenateRange.Cells(i).Value
    End If
Next i
If xResult <> "" Then
    xResult = VBA.Mid(xResult, VBA.Len(Separator) + 1)
End If
ConcatenateIf = xResult
Exit Function
End Function
```

Later on you can use it, if you enable macro in your workbook.
In your specific example write the following formula into F2 cell and copy over needed range.

```
=ConcatenateIf($A2:$E2,"YES",$A$1:$E$1,",")
```

Answer (score 2):

In F2 copy-paste this formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF($A2="YES",A$1&",",),IF($B2="YES",B$1&",",),IF($C2="YES",C$1&",",),IF($D2="YES",D$1&",",),IF($E2="YES",E$1&",",))
```

and drag down against the column.

Explanation:

```
IF($A2="YES",A$1&",",)
IF($B2="YES",B$1&",",)
IF($C2="YES",C$1&",",)
IF($D2="YES",D$1&",",)
IF($E2="YES",E$1&",",)
```

The above code has been rewritten 5 times and the column name has been changed. It checks whether the cell in the current row has a 'YES'. If it does then it'll enter the header of the column which is `'A$1'`. Notice that $1 is absolute reference to the first row i.e. the header.

In the end, I have encapsulated all the five `IF` statements using `CONCATENATE` statement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan. That works great, but i was wondering if there was a more easier to manage solution - maybe using array formulas. I never thought of mentioning it in my original post, but my spreadsheet has a couple of hundred columns.  That means a couple of hundred IF statements.  If I add or remove a column at any time (something that will happen fairly frequently), I will need to keep updating all the IF statements.

Comment: I'll check and get back to you.